# When plotting with Bokeh, how do you automatically cycle through a color pallette?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I want to use a loop to load and/or modify data and plot the result within the loop using Bokeh (I am familiar with [Matplotlib's `axes.color_cycle`](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/api/color_cycle.html)).  Here is a simple example

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
output_file('bokeh_cycle_colors.html')

p = figure(width=400, height=400)
x = np.linspace(0, 10)

for m in xrange(10):
    y = m * x
    p.line(x, y, legend='m = {}'.format(m))

p.legend.location='top_left'
show(p)
```

which generates this plot

[image: bokeh plot]

How do I make it so the colors cycle without coding up a list of colors and a modulus operation to repeat when the number of colors runs out?

There was some discussion on GitHub related to this, issues [351](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/351) and [2201](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2201), but it is not clear how to make this work.  The four hits I got when searching the [documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/search.html?q=cycle+colors) for `cycle color` did not actually contain the word `cycle` anywhere on the page.

Comment: The [color cycler](http://matplotlib.org/cycler/) package, developed as part of matplotlib, may be useful for creating a dictionary that could be used to cycle more than just the color.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It is probably easiest to just get the list of colors and cycle it yourself using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html):

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

# select a palette
from bokeh.palettes import Dark2_5 as palette
# itertools handles the cycling
import itertools  

output_file('bokeh_cycle_colors.html')

p = figure(width=400, height=400)
x = np.linspace(0, 10)

# create a color iterator
colors = itertools.cycle(palette)    

for m, color in zip(range(10), colors):
    y = m * x
    p.line(x, y, legend='m = {}'.format(m), color=color)

p.legend.location='top_left'
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: You could also create the iterator then set `color=next(colors)` to skip the `zip`.

Answer (score 10):

You can define a simple generator that cycles colors for you.

In python 3:

```
from bokeh.palettes import Category10
import itertools

def color_gen():
    yield from itertools.cycle(Category10[10])
color = color_gen()
```

or in python 2 (or 3):

```
from bokeh.palettes import Category10
import itertools

def color_gen():
    for c in itertools.cycle(Category10[10]):
        yield c
color = color_gen()
```

and when you need a new color, do:

```
p.line(x, y1, line_width=2, color=color)
p.line(x, y2, line_width=2, color=color)
```

Here is the above example:

```
p = figure(width=400, height=400)
x = np.linspace(0, 10)

for m, c in zip(range(10), color):
    y = m * x
    p.line(x, y, legend='m = {}'.format(m), color=c)

p.legend.location='top_left'
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: The `color_gen` functions amount to wrappers on `itertools.cycle` that don't actually do anything.

Answer (score 7):

Two small changes will make prior answer work for Python 3.

- changed: `for m, color in zip(range(10), colors):`
- prior: `for m, color in itertools.izip(xrange(10), colors):`

Answer (score 4):

In Python > 3.7 you could do something like this:

```py
from bokeh.palettes import Category10_10
       
color = Category10_10.__iter__()

p.line(x, y1, line_width=2, color=next(color))
```

This will cycle through each element of the list until exhausted each time you use `next()`.

Every sequence type in python can return an iterator object.

Comment: This method has one disadvantage. The iterator is not cyclic. the 11th call of next() will raise exception.

Comment: Very true, I was just putting forward a minimal example highlighting the in-build iterator object from sequence types

Comment: I'd say `color = iter(Category10_10)` would be strongly preferable.

Comment: Same thing but yes you're right it looks nicer