# Bokeh legend scroll

Tags: python, bokeh

When generating a bokeh plot using python with many categories, for instance a bar plot, the legend will not fit entirely in the screen and it is not possible to scroll.

Is there a way to scroll a legend?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no scroll option for the legend.

Some suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51394638/python-bokeh-legend-out-of-the-plot-size) answer:

- The legend is drawn on the same canvas as the plot, so you could show more of your legend by increasing the plot size.
- You could decrease the legend font size with `p.legend.label_text_font_size = "8px"`

Comment: I would add, there is an [open issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3880) to make Legend "tabular" (i.e. with rows and columns) but it is not implemented yet as of 1.3.4.

Comment: Since the release of bokeh 3.1 (march '23) the option of grided tabulare exists.